# Why here is crooked line in $\log(\frac{a+1}{c+1})$ contour plot?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I plotted contour plot of this formula by Wolfram Alpha
$$\log(\frac{a+1}{c+1}), 0 < a < 1000, 0 < c < 1000$$ 
[the contour plot of the above formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7xLc.gif)

In the above figure, there is a crooked line in the bottom part.
If I plot this, there is no crooked line.$$\log(\frac{a}{c}), 0 < a < 1000, 0 < c < 1000$$

Why there is crooked line in the first case?

Comment: It may come from the way Wolfram Alpha is dealing with implicit constraints  $f(x)=c$ in contour plots. It looks like it treats those numerically, not symbolically. But it is just a guess. Of course, there should not be such a zigzag series in reality as the level sets are straight lines in both cases.

Comment: I got [this reply](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1224092) from Wolfram Alpha community. 
Like you said, it seems like it is because of the way of plotting points. Thanks for the comment